# How to call form-data with key-value in rest request using Retrofit Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, retrofit, native

[image]

I want to send rest request in this specific format i.e. form-data with `key="image"` and `value=selected file`

I am trying this way but it is not working in my case

```
@Multipart
@POST("dashboard/media")
suspend fun upload(@Part("image") image: MultipartBody.Part): UploadMediaResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

First create form-data using MultipartBody.Part:

```
val file = File("selected file")
val requestFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file)
val imageBody: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile)
```

After send 'imageBody' to retrofit:

```
 //apiInterface.upload(imageBody);

@Multipart
@POST("dashboard/media")
suspend fun upload(@Part image: MultipartBody.Part): UploadMediaResponse
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not working for me